# linux kernel code ">>" operator

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

We've been given an assignment to make some modifications to Linux kernel code and recompile it. I'm having hard time figuring out what does this code line do:

```
p->time_slice = (current->time_slice + 1) >> 1;
```

To be more exact, why there's ">> 1" at the end?

Comment: Because the algorithm which this code implements specifies that the value should be shifted to the right by one bit.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question? bks is trying to learn; this is a class assignment, and he's probably still learning C. Asking questions is a good way to do so. Telling him not to hack on the Linux kernel and downvoting the question doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @BrianCampbell Don't take me wrong, but isn't the `>>` operator explained in any decent C tutorial?

Comment: @H2CO3 Maybe; though it is a bit obscure if you're not doing bit twiddling, so I can imagine some possibly glossing over it, or someone learning not remembering it if they didn't have the context to understand why it was important when they first went over it. Regardless, this question was not unclear, and this is something that is hard to search for as most search engines don't handle special character well. Downvoting the question and insulting the person asking it are mean-spirited and not helpful.

Comment: @H2CO3, or possibly the OP has had C++/iostreams exposure only and knows `>>` as the extraction operator, wondering what it means in this context.

Comment: OK, I really don't understand the people who closed this question. If this question is too localized, then almost every question on this site is too localized. Asking "here is some syntax I don't understand, what does it mean?" is not a particularly localized question; the syntax, and explanations in the answer, are applicable to any C code. The fact that he happened to ask this in the context of the Linux kernel is irrelevant. Why do people feel the need to downvote and close perfectly good questions from beginners? We're here to help, not to shame people into looking elsewhere for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

">>" means to shift the value bitwise to the right. "x >> y" is the same as dividing by 2^y and truncating the result. Truncating the result means rounding down in almost all cases, however with negative numbers there may exist alternate implementations. Please see comments if you think this is happening to you.

Comment: *as dividing by two and truncating the result.

Comment: Ouh, and rounding towards zero. Truncation rounds *up* in case of negative integers.

Comment: @H2CO3: it's *not* the same as truncation; it's equivalent to truncation for positive values and implementation-defined for negative values (and most common implementations will round negative values down).

Comment: @StephenCanon Right. I think we are going to freak out poor dbeer in the near future. :P

Comment: @H2CO3, @ Stephen Caron -- just **to make things clear**: in the case of negative numbers you have **TWO possible outcomes** /implementations: **(1)** shift with sign extension, which truncates DOWN (towards negative infinity, not zero), or **(2)** shift WITHOUT sign extension, which completely changes the meaning of the number (-1 >> 1 becomes a very very large positive number.)

Comment: There's a reason that I said "rounded down", as in the implementation that the person asking the question is likely to be using (GCC, given that he or she is compiling the Linux kernel), this is the behavior.

Comment: @BrianCampbell, why not put that rationale in your answer instead of these comments?  Doing that will also help the poor sucker who stumbles over this question from google but is NOT using gcc and is NOT looking at the linux kernel.

Comment: @vladr I've put a more complete explanation in my answer, though it's a bit moot now that this answer's been accepted.

Comment: @dbeer You might want to update your answer again, to prevent confusion. Right shifting does not ever round up; if sign extension is used, it rounds down (towards negative infinity).

Comment: @vladr: does the C standard actually specify that those are the only two options somewhere?  I could be missing it, but I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: No, @StephenCanon **the real world** of machine instruction sets essentially guarantee that those are the only two options. *How many angels do you think can dance on the head of a pin?*  Sheesh. :)

Comment: @vladr: consider an anomaly from the history of **the real world** of machine instruction sets: what is the behavior of a signed right shift on a ones-complement architecture?  (Not that I expect many programmers to run into a CDC6000 anytime soon).

Answer (score 5):

That's a bitwise shift operator. Treating a value as an array of bits, it shifts everything one bit to the right (towards the least significant bit). This is the equivalent of dividing by 2, rounded down, for positive numbers. Shifting is used as a quick way to divide by a power of 2; if you shift by 1 (`>> 1`), you are dividing by 2, if you shift by 2 (`>> 2`), you are dividing by 4, and so on.

For example, here are a couple of examples of how this would work, if you were using 4 bit integers:

```
6 >> 1
  0110  ->  0011 
               3

7 >> 1
  0111  ->  0011
               3

6 >> 2
  0110  ->  0001
               1
```

For negative numbers, it is a bit more complicated. The C standard does not specify the format of negative numbers. On most modern machines, they are stored in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement); that is, to represent a negative number, you take the positive representation, invert every bit, and add 1. The most significant bit is then taken to indicate the sign bit. If you right shift a negative number, there are two possible interpretations; one in which you always shift a 0 into the most significant bit, one in which you shift in a matching value to what was already there, known as "sign extension."

```
-2 >> 1
   1110  ->  0111
                7
   1110  ->  1111
               -1
```

The C standard does not specify which of these interpretations an implementation must use. GCC does the more expected one, sign extension, which is equivelent to dividing by two and rounding down, just like the positive case. Note that rounding down means "towards negative infinity", not "towards zero" as you might assume.

```
-3 >> 1
   1101  ->  1110
               -2
```